# Lightroom destroying RAWs during import

Tags: raw, import

When I import raws (5D mark III and/or 6d) into Lightroom (5.5- 5.7) it sometimes does this to to actual file during import: 
[image: lightroom error]

The files on the card are normal and undamaged. Anybody got an idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: How do you know the files on the card are normal and undamaged? If you're looking at them in camera or with any normal viewer, you're looking at the embedded JPEG preview, not the full file. I strongly suspect your files are just corrupt.

Comment: When I plugin the card into the computer and look at the raw files using another program like the regular OSX imageviewer or capture one they are ok

Comment: also, if I copy them by hand, eg. drag and drop them, and tell lightroom to regenerate the smart preview, they are fine

Comment: If you can drag-drop to copy them successfully, can you then tell Lightroom to import that copied file successfully? In other words, does it matter whether you import form the memory card?

Comment: I tried that and Lightroom destroys it anyway no matter from where I import

Comment: Have you confirmed that when viewing the images with OSX imageviewer or capture one they are actually using the RAW data, or are they just using the embedded JPEG preview? It still sounds like your files are corrupt but the JPEG previews are not.

Answer (score 0):

did you try another usb port ?
did you try usb transfert by connecting your camera to your pc ?

check also errors on your hard drive ...

Check your memory : http://www.cnet.com/how-to/test-your-ram-with-windows-memory-diagnostic-tool/

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer (although I appreciate you can't comment yet).

Comment: The usb ports and the memory is fine. It makes no difference, if I attach the camera via USB or use the internal card reader or an external one

Comment: @BenediktWutzi, change CF card, for me it seems like it is corrupted. And LR do not destroy them, software just show what is inside raw files (camera normally show jpg preview from raw file)